how to include symlinks with deno deploy
I'm trying to share some interfaces between my frontend (angular) and my backend (deno). So next to these 2 project folders, have added another one called shared-interfaces, and symlinked it into the angular and deno folders:
frontend-angular/
  src/
    ...frontend code...
    shared-interfaces (symlink)
backend-deno
  api/
    ...backend code...
    shared-interfaces (symlink)
shared-interfaces/
  ...shared interfaces...

This works fine when developing locally, however, I can't get it to work with deno deploy:
error: The deployment failed: Module not found "file:///src/shared-interfaces/somefile.ts".

On the Angular side, I had to add "preserveSymlinks": true to angular.json > project > my-project > architect > build > options, then it compiles successfully.
Is there something equivalent I can do on the Deno side so that it works with Deno Deploy?
If not, what are some other option I have for sharing interfaces between a Deno and Angular project?

I don't see anything about this in the Deno Deploy docs. I also don't see any GitHub issues including the word symlink — you might consider asking about this in a new issue.
As a workaround — is it important that the actual files reside in the ./shared-interfaces directory… or could you relocate them to ./backend-deno/shared-interfaces and then update the symlinks in ./frontend-angular/shared-interfaces?

^ And depending on the tools you're using, hard links might also be a more suitable choice for this scenario… but be sure to research because some tools will un-link such file nodes and cause fragmentation (commonly by deleting and re-creating files instead of directly modifying).
